# Is there any way how to scan for advertisement channels to get access to HC-06 bluetooth controller?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm quite new in Arduino and Bluetooth devices, but need to demostrate some vulnerabilities of IoT devices and I want to try hack HC-06 bluetooth controller to send instruction to Arduino. I want to try MAC spoofing method and second method is about exploiting advertisement channels of BLE devices by sniffing. I don't actually know if HC-06 is considered as BLE device or if it has advertisement channels.

I'm really new in this field and I've just read some articles about basics. This is used as a school project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HC-06 is not a BLE device, is Bluetooth v2.0 + EDR and it does not has advertisement channels.

Go for HM-10 to have a proper BLE device.

---

Some references that may help you to get into the topic:

Old documentation about BR/EDR versions:

https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-121r2.pdf

Recent documentation on BLE security:

https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/sp/800-121/rev-1/final/documents/draft-sp800-121_rev1.pdf